# Are these spider mites on my indoor eggplant?

Tags: identification, pests, insects, spider-mites

Yes, numerous questions on the subject but I have some nice photos. These bugs are running along the webs quite freely so the webs are presumably made by them.

They are on my indoor eggplant and I didn't see them last week. Only saw a few webs. But now they're obvious.

The only hesitation I have in identification is that they're readily visible, though just under 1 mm (1/3 in) in size, but the references I've seen say you need a hand glass to see them.

These photos were taken with a macro lens attached to my phone. I've since soaked the whole plant in neem oil.

[image: Spider mites]
[image: More webs]

As per comment request, here's the whole plant.

[image: whole plant]

Comment: Now, I've seen baby spiders that look just like this.  The scale for spider mites is mighty small.  Can you see these guys with your naked eye? Then they WERE baby spiders.  You said you only saw a few 'webs'...I'd like to see the entire plant as spider mite really sucks the life out of a plant.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/AGXbR0X.jpg but I only see 6 legs so they're not spiders.

Comment: Nice photos then!  Take your plant into the shower, spray with NEEM, beneath the leaves, tops, top of soil, allow to dry, then turn the shower (cold) and allow to take a long one.  Allow to drain and dry again then take it back to its spot.  Check in a week and you might have to do this again...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, spider mites, and quite a heavy infestation.  Next they start [floating to other plants](http://www.just4growers.com/stream/pests-and-diseases/all-about-spider-mites.aspx).  Get the soap and water out quick or throw the plant out.

The key to success with soap is to apply at 5 - 6 day intervals to get the eggs after they hatch.

Adding a bit of isopropyl alcohol as a desiccant can help

Comment: I sprayed the whole plant with pyrethrum last week so am surprised to see so many mites this week hence swapping to neem this week.